# Change this function to make the cookie expire to 30 seconds

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

How can I change this function to expire instead of days in 30 seconds?, I have no idea about this.. and its from Telerik

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) function:

```
var numberOfSeconds = 30;
var exdate = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 1000 * numberOfSeconds);
```

Comment: do i need to change expiredays to numberOfSeconds? in the signature?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.getDate()` and `.setDate()` (which get and set the day-of-the-month), use getSeconds:

```
exdate = new Date(exdate.setSeconds(exdate.getSeconds()+30));
```